# jQuery - Search Mysql for results, then display within table, but also have a click link for each record

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Ive spent several hours trying to resolve an issue with very limited experience with jQuery which is not helping me.

I am wanting to search a database for a list of results using a few input fields and then a submit button, when you click submit the values are passed to a .php script which returns the results and these are displayed in a table within a div container which works perfect.

Each record is then displayed in its own row within the table, with columns for different data.

record number
name
town

What i want is for the record number to be a click link of some kind, which when clicked, it then passes that value and does a different mysql request displaying that unique records data in more detail in a different div container. This is the part i cant get to work as i believe its something to do with BINDING, or the .ON which i dont really know anything or understand how it works, as my experience is very limited.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".click").click(function() {
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var name = $(this).attr("id");
                $('#2').load("mysqlrequest_unique.php?recordid=" +name);
            });

            $("#get").click(function() {
                var sales_record_number     = "sales_record_number="    + $("#sales_record_number").val() + "&";
                var item_id                 = "item_id="                + $("#item_id").val() + "&";
                var user_id                 = "user_id="                + $("#user_id").val() + "&";
                var buyer_fullname          = "buyer_fullname="         + $("#buyer_fullname").val() + "&";
                var sale_date               = "sale_date="              + $("#sale_date").val() + "&";
                var paypal_transaction_id   = "paypal_transaction_id="  + $("#paypal_transaction_id").val() + "&";
                var ship_to_zip             = "ship_to_zip="            + $("#ship_to_zip").val() + "&";
                var item_title              = "item_title="             + $("#item_title").val() + "&";

                $('#1').load("mysqlrequest_all.php?"+sales_record_number+item_id+user_id+buyer_fullname+sale_date+paypal_transaction_id+ship_to_zip+item_title, function(){
                    var name = $("#name").val();
                    var name = $(this).attr("id");
                    $('#2').load("mysqlrequest_unique.php?recordid=" +name);
                }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>

<div id="1" name='container_display_all'></div>
<div id="2" name='container_display_unique'></div>
```

This is what each row would have in the table, which doesnt work when its contained in generated html using a jQuery

```
<a class = 'click' id = '19496'>19496</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because you are adding html elements dynamically and the event handlers aren't being added to the dynamically added elements.

`$(document).ready(...)` is only run when the document loads.  So if all the elements that have the class `click` are being added dynamically, this bit of code `$(".click")` (inside `$(document).ready(...)` ) will return a jquery object that contains no elements (as there are currently none in the DOM with the class `click`).

Then later your elements (with class `click`) are added to the DOM but have no handlers on them.  What you need to do is set the handlers for those object when you add them.

So change this line:

```
$('#1').load("mysqlrequest_all.php?"+sales_record_number+item_id+user_id+buyer_fullname+sale_date+paypal_transaction_id+ship_to_zip+item_title);
```

to this:

```
$('#1').load("mysqlrequest_all.php?"+sales_record_number+item_id+user_id+buyer_fullname+sale_date+paypal_transaction_id+ship_to_zip+item_title, function(){
    $(".click").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var name = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#2').load("mysqlrequest_unique.php?recordid=" +name);
    });
}
);
```

This code will execute the function that is passed once the new html is loaded into the first div, which will add the needed handlers to the new elements.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, i have made the suggestions you said, but the problem is still there, it still doesn't work. I know the click request works as i placed a link in the main body, and when i click it the other div populates with the unique record fine. i have updated my original post to reflect the changes you suggested.

Comment: My bad, forgot to include the jquery part (i.e. `$(".class").click(...)` ) in the callback function, I've updated my answer to include it.

Comment: thank you so much, been doing my head in all evening, very happy now :)